# Changing Motorcycle piston rings

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, rebuild, nighthawk

I’m partially disassembling my engine (1984 Honda Nighthawk) to change the piston rings. Engine was failing to turn over and failing compression checks, inserting a little oil in the spark plug holes increased compression readings.

Is there anything else besides the valve stem seals I should check while I’ve got the engine open? Chat gpt suggested checking the cylinder bores for wear.

Comment: If by "piston holes" it means the cylinder bore(s), then yes. You need to mic them to see if they are beyond specifications. You need to do the same with the pistons.